# IDE or Editor with Support for Mercury

Tags: ide, editor, mercury

Are there any IDE's or editors that support Mercury besides emacs?

Comment: Which language? Eclipse has a good plugin for mercurial, and can supports languages like cpp, java, python, erlang (and I think ruby, javascript, html, css, scala as well, possibly even more)

Comment: Mercury: http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought you were talking of mercurial..

Comment: There's a NetBeans plugin, now: http://opcode.cc/projects_mercury_ide.en.html

Answer (score 6):

Distributed with Mercury is a syntax highlighting file for vim.
This is the only official editor support.  See the vim directory in the compiler's source distribution.

People say that prolog-mode for Emacs also supports Mercury, I tried this and discovered that it didn't handle Mercury specific syntax at all, and therefore was no better than using any other emacs mode.

Personally I use vim with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Codeblocks could probably be made to work with Mercury. It doesn't directly support syntax highlighting for this language but you can create a [custom lexer](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_custom_lexer_for_Code%3a%3aBlocks_editor) for it. Getting codeblocks' build system to work with the mmc compiler is just a matter of tweaking the 'advanced options' under Compiler and debugger settings.

Comment: I looked at the page and it says the languages have to be supported by scintilla. And Mercury doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

We have recently released a simple plugin for eclipse to help editing Mercury files and using along Java projects. Please take a look at it if you have Mercury under Linux and meets your requirements. Any feedback is welcome. :)

You can find it here: http://kai.mercury.mind-era.com